# WinNAT with private and external IP

Tags: networking, hyper-v, nat, windows-server-2016

I've set up a WinNAT using Microsoft [guide](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/setup-nat-network). 
All works fine until I try to add second local IP address `192.168.33.20` for private network to the same NIC.

When I make requests from VM with IP `192.168.0.2` to external network, NAT simply uses a second added IP `192.168.33.20` but not my correct external IP `11.22.33.20`.

How to make NAT translate `ExternalSourceAddress` to the correct external IP address and ignore local private IP?

```perl
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-NetNatSession

NatName                    : NATNetwork
InternalRoutingDomainId    : {b1062982-2b18-4b4f-b3d5-a78ddb9cdd49}
CreationTime               : 7/1/2019 10:18:50 AM
Protocol                   : 6
InternalSourceAddress      : 192.168.0.2 # VM IP 
InternalSourcePort         : 33114
InternalDestinationAddress : 64.233.161.113
InternalDestinationPort    : 24531
ExternalSourceAddress      : 192.168.33.20 # NAT translates to incorrect local private IP
ExternalSourcePort         : 50825
ExternalDestinationAddress : 64.233.161.113
ExternalDestinationPort    : 24531
```

```perl
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-NetNat

Name                             : NATNetwork
ExternalIPInterfaceAddressPrefix :
InternalIPInterfaceAddressPrefix : 192.168.0.0/24
IcmpQueryTimeout                 : 30
TcpEstablishedConnectionTimeout  : 1800
TcpTransientConnectionTimeout    : 120
TcpFilteringBehavior             : AddressDependentFiltering
UdpFilteringBehavior             : AddressDependentFiltering
UdpIdleSessionTimeout            : 120
UdpInboundRefresh                : False
Store                            : Local
Active                           : True
```

```perl
PS C:\Users\Administrator> route print
===========================================================================
Interface List
 11...00 d8 61 33 6d 52 ......Intel(R) I211 Gigabit Network Connection
 31...00 15 5d b3 28 07 ......Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter
  8...00 d8 61 33 6d 53 ......Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (7) I219-V
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask              Gateway       Interface         Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0              11.22.33.1    11.22.33.20       281
       11.22.33.0          255.255.255.0        On-link       11.22.33.20       281
      11.22.33.20          255.255.255.255      On-link       11.22.33.20       281
     11.22.33.255          255.255.255.255      On-link       11.22.33.20       281
      192.168.0.0          255.255.255.0        On-link       192.168.0.1       5256
      192.168.0.1          255.255.255.255      On-link       192.168.0.1       5256
    192.168.0.255          255.255.255.255      On-link       192.168.0.1       5256
     192.168.33.0          255.255.255.0        On-link       11.22.33.20       281
    192.168.33.20          255.255.255.255      On-link       11.22.33.20       281
   192.168.33.255          255.255.255.255      On-link       11.22.33.20       281
        224.0.0.0          240.0.0.0            On-link       1                 331
        224.0.0.0          240.0.0.0            On-link       11.22.33.20       281
        224.0.0.0          240.0.0.0            On-link       192.168.0.1       5256
  255.255.255.255          255.255.255.255      On-link       1                 331
  255.255.255.255          255.255.255.255      On-link       11.22.33.20       281
  255.255.255.255          255.255.255.255      On-link       192.168.0.1       5256
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address           Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     11.22.33.1             Default
===========================================================================
```

```perl
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-NetNatExternalAddress

ExternalAddressID : 19
NatName           : NATNetwork
IPAddress         : 11.22.33.20
PortStart         : 50299
PortEnd           : 50398
Active            : True

ExternalAddressID : 20
NatName           : NATNetwork
IPAddress         : 11.22.33.20
PortStart         : 64012
PortEnd           : 64111
Active            : True

ExternalAddressID : 27
NatName           : NATNetwork
IPAddress         : 192.168.33.20
PortStart         : 50796
PortEnd           : 50895
Active            : True

ExternalAddressID : 28
NatName           : NATNetwork
IPAddress         : 192.168.33.20
PortStart         : 59684
PortEnd           : 59783
Active            : True
```

```perl
PS C:\Users\Administrator> ipconfig

Windows IP Configuration

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Ethernet adapter vEthernet (NATSwitch):

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::5d32:dd47:60a3:9184%31
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Ethernet adapter Ethernet 2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::9592:ef20:9c15:b759%8
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 11.22.33.20      # external IP 
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.33.20    # local private IP
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 11.22.33.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not see that your Scenario is listed in the link you have provided for Microsoft Guide. A proper setup would require you to add additional NIC and assign it the Private IP Address you would like to use, instead of using One NIC with multiple IP addresses.