# How to bind an external IP address to a new NetNat network?

Tags: networking, hyper-v, nat

On my Hyper-V 2019 server, which is joined to the domain that's hosted on one of its VMs, I'm running on the `192.168.0.0/24` subnet. I'm setting up a demo of a new DC for a customer, so I need it to run on a different subnet, `192.168.4.0/24`.

To accommodate this, I've created a NAT network following [this guidance](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/setup-nat-network). It works. However, I'd like to go a step further than what the guidance provides for. I'd like to be able to RDP into the new server from within VMs on the `192.168.0.0/24` range.

The general concept for doing this seems to be addressed in [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/973662), and also in [this guidance](https://petri.com/using-nat-virtual-switch-hyper-v), but detailed how-to configuration steps elude me. Search results aren't turning up much beyond what I've already done.

I must admit that I haven't tried anything toward this, as I don't want to risk making a newbie-type mistake and fouling up what I already have that works. I hope to hear from the experts on this one, those who already know how to do it and can explain the necessary steps.

How can I allow access into VMs on the internal `192.168.4.0/24` range from VMs on the external `192.168.0.0/24` range?